# Error trying to convert a group command result to integer

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, scripting

Hi I am trying to find and delete a duplicate node in Sharepoint Web.Config file under the  node , so far i am able to get to the node using the following query

```
$app = Get-SPWebApplication "http://mysite"
$apppath = $app.IisSettings[[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUrlZone]::Default].Path.ToString()
$path = $apppath + "\web.config"
$filecontents = [xml](Get-Content $path)
$dupRecords = $filecontents. configuration."system.webServer".modules.add |
              Group-Object name |
              where { $_.count -ne 1} |
              select [int]{$_.count}
```

When I try this it fails with the following error:

> `$dupRecords = $filecontents. configuration."system.webServer".modules.add | Group-Object name | where { $_.count -ne 1} | select [int]{$_.count}`

Does anyone know if there is a a better way to solve this issue or what is wrong with my command?

Comment: Remove the `[int]` or move it inside the script block

Comment: Please show the complete error message.